# need help on unix Script to read a data from specific position and use the extracted in query

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sh, ksh

Input file:

```
ADSDWETTYT017775227ACG
ADSDWETTYT029635225HCG
ADSDWETTYC018525223JCG
ADSDWETTYC987415221ACG
ADSDWETTCC891235219ACG
ADSDWETTTT074565217ACG
ADSDWETTYT567895213ACG
ADSDWETTYH037535215ACG
ADSDWETTYC051595211ACG
ADSDWETTYT052465209ACG
ADSDWETTYT067595207ACG
ADSDWETTYT077515205ACG
```

need to check the 10 position on the file contain/start with T, if its start with "T" then i need to take the value from 14 char from 16.

from the above file am expecting the below output,

```
'5227','5225','5217','5213','5209','5207','5205'
```

this result i should assigned to some constant like (result below) and should be used in the query where clause like below,

```
result=$(awk '
        BEGIN{
        conf="" };
{       if(substr($0,10,1)=="T"){
        conf=substr($0,16,4);

{NT==1?s="'\''"conf:s=s"'\'','\''"conf}
}
}
END {print s"'\''"}
' $INPUT_FILE_PATH  

db2 "EXPORT TO ${OUTPUT_FILE}  OF DEL select STATUS FROM TRAN where TN_NR in (${result})"
```

I need some help to enhance the awk command and passing the constant in query where clause. kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts; please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v s1="'" 'BEGIN{OFS=", "} substr($0,10,1)=="T"{val=(val?val OFS:"") (s1 substr($0,16,4) s1)} END{print val}'  Input_file
```

Adding non-one liner form of above code:

```
awk -v s1="'" '
BEGIN{ OFS=", " }
substr($0,10,1)=="T"{
  val=(val?val OFS:"") (s1 substr($0,16,4) s1)
}
END{
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

To save output of this code into a shell variable try following:

`value=$(awk -v s1="'" 'BEGIN{OFS=", "} substr($0,10,1)=="T"{val=(val?val OFS:"") (s1 substr($0,16,4) s1)} END{print val}' Input_file)`

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -v s1="'" '             ##Starting awk program from here setting s1 to ' here.
BEGIN{ OFS=", " }           ##Setting OFS as comma space here.
substr($0,10,1)=="T"{       ##Checking condition if 10th character is T then do following.
  val=(val?val OFS:"") (s1 substr($0,16,4) s1) ##Creating val which has values from  current line as per OP requirement.
}
END{                        ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  print val                 ##Printing val here.
}
'  Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use sed for this:

```sh
sed -En '/^.{9}T/ s/^.{15}(....).*/\1/p' file
```

And then to get your exact output, pipe that into

```sh
...  | sed "s/.*/'&'/" | paste -sd,
```

Comment: You could add the `'`s around `\1` in the first `sed` if you just change the delimiting quotes on that one from `'` to `"` and then you'd just have `sed | paste` instead of `sed | sed | paste`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `perl` over `awk` here for its better arrays (in particular, joining one into a string). Something like:

```
perl -nE "push @n, substr(\$_, 15, 4) if /^.{9}T/;
          END { say join(',', map { \"'\$_'\" } @n) }" "$INPUT_FILE_PATH"
```

Comment: @jcrshankar I'm not sure what you're asking